# UWP Using Live Visual Tree to edit NavigationView design

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, blend

Im struggling a little bit getitng my head around Styles and the way that you can edit particular Fluent Deisgn effects such as the rollover Highlight etc.

Ive discovered the Live Visual Tree that is displaying exactly the parts that i need to edit the style of (Aka just delete them).

I was wondering if there is a way of interpreting the Live visual tree to be useful when directing the XAML style. It doesn't seem as though you can edit components directly through the visual tree so im a little stuck.

Here is an image of my current visual tree and highlighted the part id like to get rid of. 
Id like to point out i have no idea what im doing so please excuse the ignorance[image]

As requested, my use case is as follows:

I have a NavigationView that has an set of AppBarButtons nested within a Horizontal Stack Panel. As the Stackpanel is set to a NavigationViewMenuItem, it allows the stackpanel to be selected which i do not want. I want to remove the rectangle, the rollover effect for the stackpanel and only make the buttons selectable and have rollover effects.

Here is the picture for demonstration:

[image]

Here is the XAML for the MainPage StackPanel aswell so you get an idea of the layout:

```
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <!-- Need to sort out the rollover effect for the toolbar and make it non-selectable. Will resolve later-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="AppBarButtons" Tag="AppBarButtonPanel" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=NavView, Path=IsPaneOpen}">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="NewFile_ClickAsync" ToolTipService.ToolTip="New Budget"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="OpenFile_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Open Budget"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SaveButton_ClickAsync" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save Budget"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Budget Settings"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Calculator" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Calculator_Open" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="CalcButton_ClickAsync" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Open Windows Calculator"/>
                </StackPanel>


                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
```

Edit for visual styles after Editing a Copy
[image]

Comment: please add a bit more detail about your usecase, as of what is the current behaviour and what behaviour of navigationview items you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you can use LivePropertyViewer to edit properties nd see change in UI, but that only affects the current debugging session.

Comment: Edited as requested. Hope it helps clarify. Ive bumped into editing properties but the fact it doesnt save is really annoying. I can edit exactly what i need in the live tree but it just doesnt carry over once debugging is terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your **StackPanel** ( which has all the buttons stacked horizontally ) from **NavigationMenuItem** to **PaneFooter**.

```
<NavigationView.PaneFooter> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="AppBarButtons" Tag="AppBarButtonPanel" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=NavView, Path=IsPaneOpen}">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="NewFile_ClickAsync" ToolTipService.ToolTip="New Budget"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="OpenFile_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Open Budget"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SaveButton_ClickAsync" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save Budget"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Budget Settings"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Calculator" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Calculator_Open" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="CalcButton_ClickAsync" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Open Windows Calculator"/>
    </StackPanel>
</NavigationView.PaneFooter>
```

the reason you re getting left selection indicator is because every **NavigationMenuItem** shows it when it is selected and you have just a toolbar which should not be in NavigationMenuItem.

Comment: Amazing! This is some pretty cool functionality! I will do as you suggested and delve deeper into this. Thank you for the advice and solution :) Great help as always

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: Touseefbsb, im having huge issues here trying to get this to work :( Im really not sure what im doing wrong still. For some reason, it just wont allow me to do what youve suggested

Comment: what exactly you tried? were you able to spot the "SelectionIndicator" within the template?

Comment: Unfortunately, Selection Indicator does not come up at all. I can see rootGrid as mentioned but selectionIndicator is not there at all :/ Ive gone through and tried tweeking a few things myself to no avail

Comment: When i do as suggested and edit a copy of the control, it creates a HUGE page of XAML Styles, nothing in there has SelectionIndicator or anything of the sorts. Ive attached an image to the original post

Comment: are you editing the NavigationViewItem template or the template of NavigationView itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179765/discussion-between-touseefbsb-and-batteredburrito).